# Security token for MicrosoftAppId: '' is unauthorized to post to connector

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I have written a BOT using the BOT Application template in VS 2015 and published it to my Azure account. I registered here https://dev.botframework.com/. I'm using the Facebook Messenger Channel. I have setup the webhooks, entered the credentials correctly and verified them. However when I try to test the bot I get this error...

"Security token for MicrosoftAppId: '' is unauthorized to post to connector!"

Obviously the message itself seems pretty clear, but I've checked that the security token is correct. Is there anything else that might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to put your MicrosoftAppId into web.config file?

Comment: No that's definitely not it. I have checked and rechecked numerous times. Thanks for the input though.